# Advise on proper placement of floor threshold

Tags: floor

I have just widened my kitchen by two feet.  As well I removed a small 45 degree wall and straightened out the doorway into the bedroom.  As you can see in the Before Image, the threshold between the vinyl and parquet floors followed the 45 degree line.

Here's the "before" plan:

[image: Previous layout]

Here's the after plan:

[image: New layout, with possibilities]

In the new layout, my wife and I disagree as to where the new vinyl floor should end.  My choice is red line in image AFTER and my wife is partial to where the green line is placed.

Opinions on this would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the flooring in the hall? Would the BR/hall/LR flooring match?

Comment: The bedroom door is now more or less **in** the kitchen. The green line shows this off more, the red line location sets it back a little better. If it wasn't for that second awkwardly turned bedroom door, I'd probably go with the green as well. But since it's where it is, I believe the red is the way to go.

Comment: I didn't even have to look at your drawings to know that your wife is right. She is always right and always will be right. (For you, happy wife = happy life.) In seriousness, though, I'd vote for your choice.

Answer (score 1):

Okay but, you still owe her a dinner & flowers you know. Any gloating will blacklist your butt & mine for years. I have to agree with your red line. As a normal & accepted by family, friends & neighbors practice. The transition should happen only at the room's opening, not some horribly disfigured hallway.

The vinyl is the oddball & is surrounded by parquet, so sorry but the parquet wins 3 to 1, literally. Now, the green isn't bad. But for me, it's in the wrong place. I would've possibly gone for the green if it were pulled back to the other end of the living room's passage way, where the hall & each room had a full threshold surrounding the vinyl. But really, it still wouldn't make sense & the vinyl would be just plain grotesque.